# Are the graphs of $a\sin(x)$ and $\sin(ax)$ similar?

Tags: trigonometry

Are the graphs of $\sin(ax)$ and $a\sin{x}$ similar in some way? By similar, I mean that if you were to zoom in (or change the length/width while maintaining the proportion) and move the graphs a bit, they would be able to line up perfectly. The reason I'm asking this is that I'm learning about trig functions, and realized that $a\sin{x}$ means that the graph $\sin{x}$ is stretched vertically by a factor of $a$, while $\sin(ax)$, means that the graph is horizontally compressed by a factor of $a$, which should mean that the ratio between the height and width should be $a$, right? If this is true, then what sort of transformations should I do to one graph in order to get the other (I'm pretty sure this is just some zoom-in on the graph, but how do I 'zoom in' on a graph)?

Comment: Have you tried graphing, say $y = 3\sin (x)$ together with $y^* = \sin(3x)$ on the same Cartesian Coordinate graph?

Comment: The graph of $\sin(ax)$ is compressed by a factor of $a$ on the $x$-axis, while the graph of $a\sin(x)$ is stretched by $a$ on the $y$-axis (both compared to the graph of $\sin(x)$). Therefore, if you were to change the aspect ratio between the axis you will see the same graph.

Comment: The graph of $a \sin(x)$ is obtained from that of $\sin(ax)$ by stretching by a factor $a$ on both axes.

Comment: @DennisGulko Great, that confirms it! Is there any way to transform one graph to the other?

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about $a\sin(x)$, you are referring to a stretching of $a$ the function $\sin(x)$ on $y-$axis, while $\sin(ax)$ is the stretching of $\sin(x)$ in the $x-$axis.
From here we understood how we can pass from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$. Basically, if you start from $f(x)=a\sin(x)$ and you want to reach $g(x)=\sin(ax)$ then you have to stretch the graph of $f(x)$ by:
$$\delta(a,a)$$
where $\delta(x,y)$ is the stretching over $x,y$. To pass from $g(x)$ to $f(x)$, you have to use:
$$\delta(1/a,1/a)$$

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't really understand this answer. what is $\delta(x, y)$ for?

Comment: @Apoqlite: as I have written in the post, $\delta(x, y)$ is the stretching of the graph of the function with coeficents $x,y$ on $x,y-$axis.